# MySQL User with Host set to a Range of IP Addresses

Tags: mysql, users

I have a hosted MySQL DB that I need to give access to from my customers site. They have a fast broadband connection which can present them with a range of IP addresses from a fixed pool.

So I need to lock down the access to their MySQL user so that the Host setting is a range of addresses within a class. Not the whole class.

I realise I can use a wildcard such as 81.91.71.% but that is too generous. Their range is more like

81.10.20.1 --> 81.10.20.15

Is there a way to do this other than create 15 users, one for each individual IP address?
thanks
Mark

Answer (score 21):

you can use the grant assign to a netmask like:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'user'@'81.10.20.1/255.255.255.240';
```

It will give you access from 81.10.20.1 -> 81.10.20.14, just change the subnet part to fit the range you need.

You can see more info at mysql doc [account names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/account-names.html)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for offering this idea but I did take a look at the MySQL link you provided before posting and it does say that netmasks can only be used on 8, 16, 24 or 32 bits of the address. In other words, only whole classes of address. The example states that  255.255.255.240 wont work.

Answer (score 5):

For IP ranges MySQL only allows you to use % as a "anything" wild card or an underscore for a single digit.

Alternatively you could setup reverse DNS to have desired IPs resolved to something like mysql-%.mydomain.com

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question.

Controlling access via an IP address might be better solved at a different layer in your stack. A server firewall for example (iptables,firewalld,etc..) could filter access to MySQL from a specific range.

If you often offer connections to externals folks; A VPN or SSH bastion would give you control over the ip your client is getting. Bonus: You get an encrypted connection.
(MySQL's protocol isn't encrypted by default. It's extra effort to setup encrypted connections.)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the same user multiple times, but with different IP address. MySQL allows that.